# Column does not exist Laravel Factory

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-7

I have a table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('place_id');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->dateTime('utc_date');
        $table->dateTime('local_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('parties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('place_id');

        $table->foreign('place_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('places')
            ->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}
```

and model factory

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Models\Party;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Party::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $date = $faker->dateTimeBetween(now()->subDays(3), now());

    return [
        'place_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1, 9),
        'status' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 3),
        'utc_date' => $date,
        'local_date' => \Carbon\Carbon::make($date)->addHours(3),
    ];
});
```

If i call the method create in HomeController it works correctly

```
    factory(Party::class, 10)->create();
```

but when i call it in my tests I got an error

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "utc_date" of
> relation "parties" does not exist LINE 1: insert into "parties"
> ("place_id", "status", "utc_date", "lo...
> ^ (SQL: insert into "parties" ("place_id", "status", "utc_date", "local_date",
> "updated_at", "created_at") values (5, 3, 2020-08-04 00:34:52,
> 2020-08-04 03:34:52, 2020-08-04 11:42:18, 2020-08-04 11:42:18)
> returning "id")

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\API;

use App\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use App\Models\{Party, Place};
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class PartiesControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    private User $user;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user =  factory(User::class)->create();
    }

    public function test_get_parties()
    {
        factory(Party::class)->create([
            'place_id' => factory(Place::class)->create()->id,
        ]);

        dd(Party::all());
        Sanctum::actingAs($this->user);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your Party Model, make sure that you have:
 protected $table = 'parties';

Comment: I have it. As I said above, the method create of the factory(Party::class) works fully correct if i call it in my HomeController.php

Comment: Are you using **PostgreSQL**?

Comment: Yes. I am using postgres

Comment: When it says `relation "parties" does not exist` It usually happens when your **parties** table must have been dropped before `migration:reset` rolled back

Comment: What does `use App\Models\{Party, Place};` mean? I've never seen this syntax and can't find anything about it on the PHP official website. My guess is that it groups the usage of different classes that 'live' in the same map/namespace. It looks, oh well, a little bit bizarre.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey You can find the information about grouped namespaces in official php documentation. This is a new feature of php7 https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan migrate:fresh`. If you use another database for testing and using another `.env` file then try to run `php artisan migrate:fresh --env=testing`.
For example: you can use file `env.testing` and `APP_ENV=testing` inside this file.

Maybe you added this field later and did not refresh DB. Also, check if the field exists in visual DB.
If it didn't help try to run `composer dump-autoload` and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I am using second database for testing. I connected to this db and found that this table has not been refreshed. I don't know why because I used RefreshDatabase trait. I added this field manually for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure the fillable array in model has this key,

and try using carbon instead of faker with date

```
(Carbon::now())->subDays(3);
```